# override default @types to custom

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension, typescript-generics

I have added @types/chrome in the project and want to override chrome.runtime.sendMessage types. So I have created a d.ts file and have added

```
declare namespace chrome.runtime {
  export function sendMessage(
    message: { action: 'a' | 'b'; value: string | number },
    responseCallback?: (response: any) => void
  ): void;
}
```

when I uninstall @types/chrome the custom types are used, but when I install types it doesn't work. Can anyone help with the same

Comment: Write your own `function sendMessage`, which calls the API, and use the function everywhere in your code. The function will have the type checks.

Comment: that works but looking for a typescript way to override types